# Why com.google.android could not be found in my project?

Tags: android

I download one project from Internet. And the project could not find the library : com.google.android.

[image]

I found some answers from the Internet. Like set your project's properties, but it does not work for me.

I already download the Google API from SDK 
[image]

And I set the project properties : project build target to Google API like this.
[image]

What the others things I should do?

Comment: import google play services into your project

Comment: Google API's is really useless now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the library from Google Play Service Library directory. Google Play Service Library is located here:

```
adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/extras/google
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, couple things you need to do here. That library is not a standard android library but it's usually already included in your android-sdks folder.

Firstly, unless the project you're working on is going to be a library you need to uncheck that. Go to File -> Import Existing Project and locate your android-sdks folder import the whole thing and pick and choose which projects you want, most of them are just examples but make sure you import the main library.

Next go back to your project and Add the google library as a library.